# How many languages did Vera F. Birkenbihl know?

Tags: multiple-languages

[Vera F. Birkenbihl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vera_F._Birkenbihl) (she insisted on the "F.", which stands for Felicitas) was a German management trainer and author. She coined the term "gehirn-gerechtes lernen" as a translation of "brain-friendly learning". She wrote several books about language learning based on her own unique learning method, including the following:

- [*Sprachenlernen leichtgemacht! Die Birkenbihl-Methode Fremdsprachen zu lernen*](https://www.m-vg.de/mvg/shop/article/2476-sprachenlernen-leichtgemacht/) (mvg, 2006: "Language learning made easy! The Birkenbihl method for learning foreign languages").
- [*Von Null Ahnung zu etwas Türkisch. Von Null Ahnung zu etwas Türkisch*](https://www.m-vg.de/mvg/shop/article/2046-von-null-ahnung-zu-etwas-tuerkisch/) (mvg, 2008; "From clueless to a bit of Turkish. This is not a language course").
- [*Von Null Ahnung zu etwas Japanisch. Mühelos Sprachenlernen - gehirn-gerecht und intuitiv*](https://www.m-vg.de/mvg/shop/article/1192-von-null-ahnung-zu-etwas-japanisch/) (mvg, 2008; "From clueless to a bit of Japanese. Learning languages with ease - brain-friendly and intuitive").
- [*Von Null Ahnung zu etwas Chinesisch. Mühelos Sprachenlernen - gehirn-gerecht und intuitiv*](https://www.m-vg.de/mvg/shop/article/1259-von-null-ahnung-zu-etwas-chinesisch/) (mvg, 2007; "From clueless to a bit of Chinese. Learning languages with ease - brain-friendly and intuitive")
- *Von Null Ahnung zu etwas Arabisch. Dies ist kein Sprachkurs* (mvg, 2007; "From clueless to a bit of Arabic. This is not a language course")

What I could not find, however, is which languages Vera F. Birkenbihl knew well enough to have a basic conversation or read basic texts.